# Npm install can't find version with carret

Tags: node.js, npm

I try to install package and got an error

```
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/broccoli-writer
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: broccoli-writer@'^0.1.1'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.1"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:709:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:631:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
```

But as i found

**^1.2.3 := >=1.2.3 <2.0.0**

So it should use 0.1.1 in my case

P.S i try to install package localy, change version manualy and add to local npm cache. But after 6 packages it seems crazy

P.P.S.
The problem reproduced on node 0.10.7 / npm 1.2.24

After updating to npm - 2.5.1 all work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm@1.2.24` is several years old, and no longer supported by the `npm` team. The solution to your problem, as you've found out, is simply to [update `npm`](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm). This way, you can have a version of `npm` that can actually understand what to look for when it sees the `^` semver operator. Old versions of `npm` have no idea what to look for when they see this operator because the operator is newer than the version!